# Collision of Sprites in CCSpriteBatchNode and CCParallaxNode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have two sprites one is added as the child of CCSpriteBatchNode and the other as the child of CCParallaxNode. Is there any method to detect their collision? I have used the following code.

```
 -(void)CheckCollition:(CCSprite *)Opp_Obs Opponent:(CCSprite *) H_man
{
  // NSLog(@"inside check collision");
CGRect b_rect=[Opp_Obs boundingBox];
CGPoint p_position=[H_man position];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(b_rect,p_position))
{    
    NSLog(@"collision with opponent");


    // Zoom Animation with Points
    CCScaleBy *zzomscal=[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:.12];
    CCRotateTo * rotLeft = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.2 angle:360];
    CCCallFunc *ccfun=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(zoomComplete)];
    CCSequence * zzomseq = [CCSequence actions:zzomscal,rotLeft,ccfun, nil];
    [H_man runAction:zzomseq];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"no collision");
}


}
```

But here the control never enters into the loop. Is there any other solution? Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint and compare the values of rect and position. One of them may be zero, or way off.

In the latter case you may need to convert the bbox origin and position to world coordinates first in order to compare them. This is the case when the sprites' parents are moving too (parent position != 0,0).